# I want to add text on top of a bitmap in Xamarin Forms Skia

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I would like to be able to create an infographic style image in my Xamarin Forms app.  I have a png that I am planning to use as the background and then add text on top of it.

I was trying to use these two links [Creating and drawing on SkiaSharp bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/drawing) and [SKCanvas.DrawText Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/skiasharp.skcanvas.drawtext?view=skiasharp-2.80.2) but I am getting an error on BitmapExtensions.

```
1.  Did I miss how to declare BitmapExtensions?
2.  Is this the best/easiest way to create the infographic I am trying to make?
```

Thank you!

```
       // Get text to share
       string textToShare = GamesWonText.Text + " " + GamesWon.Text + Environment.NewLine;
       textToShare += GamesLostText.Text + " " + GamesLost.Text + Environment.NewLine;
       textToShare += WinPercentText.Text + " " + WinPercent.Text + Environment.NewLine;
       textToShare += CoinsBankedText.Text + " " + CoinsBanked.Text + Environment.NewLine;
       textToShare += MaxCoinsText.Text + " " + MaxCoins.Text + Environment.NewLine;
       textToShare += AvgCoinsText.Text + " " + AvgCoins.Text + Environment.NewLine;

            // Create the image to share
            string resourceID = "Infographic Background Image.png";

            SKBitmap backgroundBitmap = BitmapExtensions.LoadBitmapResource(GetType(), resourceID);

            using (SKCanvas canvas = new SKCanvas(backgroundBitmap))
            {
                using (SKPaint paint = new SKPaint())
                {
                    paint.TextSize = 32.0f;
                    paint.IsAntialias = true;
                    paint.Color = new SKColor(0, 0, 0);
                    paint.IsStroke = false;

                    canvas.DrawText(textToShare, 540f, 960f, paint);
                }
            }
```

---

**UPDATE TO INCLUDE COMMMENT**

> The error I am getting is "CS0103: The name 'BitmapExtensions' does not exist in the current context.

Comment: "I am getting an error on BitmapExtensions" - it would be extremely helpful if you told us exactly what this error is.  At a glance, I can tell you that your resource id is not a valid resource id.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/resources-in-android/android-resource-basics?tabs=macos

Comment: How you use a bitmap is different depending on whether it is added to project as a `file` or as a `resource`. It *might* also depend on whether file is added to your shared project (the project that has xamarin forms xaml etc), or is it added to your Android Resources folder? If you click on file name in Solution Explorer, and look at Properties, what is its Build Action? For compatibility with Android, its best to only use lowercase letters (no uppercase) in the file name. Depending on folder it is in, might also need to include the *folder* (such as "Media/yourfilename.png").

Comment: I added the background image to the Resources folder on both iOS and Android.  I did that with other images and it worked fine; but I'm not trying to draw on those other images.

The error I am getting is CS0103: The name 'BitmapExtensions' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 1):

The `BitmapExtensions` is a class. You could use the code below.

```
 static class BitmapExtensions
{
    public static SKBitmap LoadBitmapResource(Type type, string resourceID)
    {
        Assembly assembly = type.GetTypeInfo().Assembly;

        using (Stream stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceID))
        {
            return SKBitmap.Decode(stream);
        }
    }

}
```

For more details, you could check the sample code in the link below. https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/main/SkiaSharpForms/Demos/Demos/SkiaSharpFormsDemos/BitmapExtensions.cs

Comment: NOTE: that code is from [Displaying SkiaSharp bitmaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/graphics/skiasharp/bitmaps/displaying#a-method-for-loading-resource-bitmaps). That doc links to [SkiaSharpFormsDemos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/skiasharpforms-demos/).